# Insecure how to refactor repeated code

Tags: java, swing, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor an old legacy java app, and I have detected code that is repeated a lot of times in the project. I'm trying to place this code in only one place, but I don't know the best solution.

The pseudocode for my problem is more or less the following:

```
public class MYDialog extends JDialog{

    private VerySpecialHardwareDevice my_device;
    private int variable1;
    private int variable3;
    private int variableXX;


    private PropertyChangeListener my_listener=new PropertyChangeListener(
        {
            //The  code of the listener interacts with the swing elements of the dialog
            //depending on the behaviour of the hardware device, and its 
            //different most of the Jdialogs/Jpanels, and its the same in a few of them.
        };


    public  MyDialog(){

        my_device=new VerySpecialHardwareDevice();
        my_device.addPropertyChangeListener(my_listener);

    }

    /*Begin of the repeated method related with the special device*/
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice1(){
     //These methods and functions use some variables like variable 1, 2, etc
    };
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice2(){...};
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice3(){...};
    (...)
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice15(){...};
    /*************************************************************/
}

public class MYPanel extends JPanel{

    private VerySpecialHardwareDevice my_device;
        private int variable1;
    private int variable3;
    private int variableXX;

    private PropertyChangeListener my_listener=new PropertyChangeListener(
        {
                //....
        };

    public  MyPanel(){

        my_device=new VerySpecialHardwareDevice();
        my_device.addPropertyChangeListener(my_listener);

    }

    /*Begin of the repeated method related with the special device*/
            private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice1(){
     //These methods and functions use some variables like variable 1, 2, etc
    };
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice2(){...};
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice3(){...};
    (...)
    private void methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice15(){...};
    /*************************************************************/
}
```

As you can see, the methods are related to a hardware device. The method from 1 to 15 are always the same, and this device is used in a lot of different Jdialogs and Jpanels accross the aplication (more than twenty forms). Each Jdialog has a property change listener which interacts with the gui depending on what the hardware device does. Most of the times these change listener are equal, but there are a few exceptions.

My first intention was to move all this code (except the listener) to a superclass, but I'm insecure because I don't know wich superclass is the best for a Jdialog and a Jpanel at once...

Maybe the is a better aproach to avoid this code repetition.

Please excuse my bad ENglish and excuse me if this question has an obvious answer.

Best regards

Comment: probably, this should go to code-review

Comment: Are methodRelatedWithSpecialHardwareDevice* functions refer any instance variables?

Comment: Yes, the functions refer variables related with the hardware device, but the variables are always the same (they are repeated too), and not related with the Dialog or the Panel. I think that the variables can be moved to another place with the code. I will reflect that in my sample.

Comment: nice example why you should _not extend_ JSomething :-) Instead, extract the hardware related stuff into its own class (as @Jens Schauder already suggested) and implement the PropertyChangeListener as a stand-alone controller that modifies the views' properties as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A superclass won't work (and is in general case a bad idea for code reuse)

create a new class holding your repeated methods. That new class will have a dependency on `VerySpecialHardwareDevice`

You dialog and frame will depend on the new class, but no longer on the `VerySpecialHardwareDevice`

In the new class create a new single method which calls the 15 duplicated methods. Your dialog and frame will call that method.

For the Listeners you might want to create seperate top level classes that can be used by frame and dialog. You might have to create a common interface implemented by frame and dialog with methods that get called by the listeners.